# Setting VBox.vgrow on a child element of <fx:root> in JavaFX 8

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I have the following .fxml file:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns:fx="javafx.com/fxml">
    <Pane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <!-- ... -->
    </Pane>
</fx:root>
```

However, there is an error at `VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"`, since `<fx:root ...` is not exactly a VBox. How can I do this in FXML (no Java)?

---

**Edit:** The error in my IDE shows "Attribute VBox.vgrow is not allowed here", and the error the Java application gives is "VBox.vgrow is not a valid attribute."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had neglected to display all my imports of the .fxml file (which only had `javafx.scene.layout.Pane`).

In order for that specific .fxml file to not give an error (see edit), the import `javafx.scene.layout.VBox` also had to be added, as `VBox.*` cannot be used on *any* element unless `VBox` is imported.

The correct .fxml file is:

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.VBox" xmlns:fx="javafx.com/fxml">
    <Pane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <!-- ... -->
    </Pane>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: If you only put a litte code fragment, no one knows about your mistakes. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to future create good questions.

Comment: @NwDx Thank you, and I apologize for making that mistake.